# How I can find the elements from two data frame with differnt length in R?

Tags: r

I have two Matrix with different width.

---

```
Matrix_A
  'data.frame':412 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ R : num  2 18 18 2 2 18 18 2 2 2 ...
 $ NS: num  4.82e+09 4.82e+09 4.82e+09 4.82e+09 4.82e+09 ...
 $ NP: chr  "20000070000" "20000000090000" "20000000060000" "20000000010000" ...
 $ NG: chr  "TE" "EC" "ET" "HT" ...
 $ DC : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

---

```
Matrix_B

  'data.frame': 2687 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ R : num  18 2 2 2 18 2 2 2 18 2 ...
 $ NS : num  4.81e+09 4.81e+09 4.81e+09 4.81e+09 4.81e+09 ...
 $ NP :chr  "20000000000400" "2000000000600" "2000000001000" "20000000007000" ...
 $ NG: chr  "HT" "HT" "TT" "TY" ...
```

---

I would like to know what elements of the Matrix A are present in the Matrix B, and to do this I wrote this code.

---

```
Matrix_B$Results <- ifelse((Matrix_A$R %in% Matrix_B$R), 
                           ifelse((Matrix_A$NS %in% Matrix_B$NS),1,0))
```

---

This dosen't give me a error, but the result is not correct.

I tried this

---

```
Matrix_B$Results <- ifelse((Matrix_A$R %in% Matrix_B$R) & 
                        (Matrix_A$NS %in% Matrix_B$NS),1,0))
```

---

but dosen't work.

Comment: The other possible dupe is [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal). See column `Matrix_A$NS`.

Comment: @phiver i don't think this question directly asks about `merging`.
Could you please give me a feedback about my solution?

Comment: I think that is not a duplicate, because I don't want to join these two table. 
I would like to know if one element of Matrix A is present in Matrix B. 
But maybe the correct way is to use the merge or join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know what elements of the Matrix A are present in the
>   Matrix B

Indeed it is subtraction of two collections:

```
A<-matrix( sample(1:5,12,replace = T ), 4, 3) 

 B<-matrix( sample(1:10,10,replace = T ), 2, 5)
```

So, the matrix A, and B could be:

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    3    3
[2,]    2    1    5
[3,]    4    4    5
[4,]    1    4    4
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    4    3   10    8    9
[2,]    1   10   10    9    6
```

Now if you wish to know, which elements are in both matrixes, you have 2 options:

Approach 1:

```
intersect(B,A)
```

Approach 2:

```
existInANotB<-setdiff(A,B)
intersect<-setdiff(A,existInANotB)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
My problem is to know which element is present in both Matrix.

Comment: @Francesco is it good now?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm studying  another solution. Have a good day.